# FastRoute - strange behaviour with localhost links in Outlook

Tags: php, fastroute

I've started using FastRoute and have a simple url for activating accounts

```
localhost/activate?key=1234567890
```

The /activate route currently does nothing more than call the handler which writes to a debug log.

If I key this url directly into the browser, it works fine and runs once.

If I click the link contained in an Outlook email (from the Outlook app) the front end controller (index.php) is ran twice. Strangely, if I put a breakpoint in the Activate Controller, it only breaks on the second instance.

Anyone seen this behaviour? I get it could be something to do with Outlook but why doesn't the debugger breakpoint on both instances and not just the second one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: index.php "ran twice" must not necessarily mean, that it also went into your Action controller each time.

Comment: The debug log is written to twice.

Comment: And that is explicitly saying, that your Activate controller was invoked?

Comment: Yes, /activate controller does nothing except write to the debug log.

Comment: Log a few more request details (including headers), to check if it is the exact same request twice, or whether they might differ in specific, relevant aspects.

Comment: What does the web server log show? Microsoft has a security service that verifies links before opening them. Obviously, `localhost` links won't be verified from the web, but if you're using a local app perhaps it tries to open them.

Comment: There could potentially be a HEAD request from Outlook. We've definitely run into issues where Slack, Teams, etc. have "clicked" a one-time-login link and expired it automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and I have to admit I am out of my depth here. However, I did manage to capture the headers for both runs. The first has a x-native-host as OneOutlook which is absent in the second. The second has the XDEBUG_SESSION which I guess it why the debugger only breakpoints the second time around. On the $_SERVER front, they are both calling the same URI but then they would be for it to run twice.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, I remember seeing something in the Fastroute documentation about HEAD requests, but (if you pardon the pun) it went way over mine!

Comment: Then, it's definitively Microsoft: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/1840

Comment: The FastRoute documentation says the a HEAD request will fallback to a GET. But both requests are of type GET.

Comment: I think the documentation means that in the absence of any specific method restrictions, HEAD and GET will be treated the same. But looking at the GitHub issue, it also sounds like MS is just sending GET requests now, anyway. You can't stop those, but you can "filter and do something somehow" if you can detect them with the `x-native-host` and/or `user-agent` headers

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHaas (& Alvaro), seems a bit of a bodge, but its working now.